# Passing of board data in board games

Tags: java, oop

Every time I make board game, I am faced with a decision. I have classes for the board and/or game logic, and another for the UI. I don't know how I should pass the board data to the UI. I could make a method on the board class that returns an array which represents the "board state", then just iterate over them on the UI. Or I can make a method that gets the value/s of a single coordinate, e.g. a `getValue(int row, int col)` method. Here are sample codes (in Java):

```
public class Board{
    private int[][] grid;
    private int rows;
    private int cols;

    // Constructor and other methods here, getRows(), getCols(), etc....

    public int getValue(int row, int col){
        return grid[row][col];
    }
}

public class UI{
    private Board board;
    // Constructor and other methods here

    public void someMethod(){
        for(int i = 0; i < board.getRows(); i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < board.getCols; j++){
                // Do something with board.getValue(i, j);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

or I can do this:

```
public class Board{
    private int[][] grid;
    private int rows;
    private int cols;

    // Constructor and other methods here, getRows(), getCols(), etc....

    public int[][] getBoardState(int row, int col){
        int[][] boardcopy = new int[][]

        for(int i = 0; i < board.getRows(); i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < board.getCols; j++){
                boardcopy[i][j] = grid[i][j];
            }
        }

        return boardcopy;
    }
}
```

What should I use? Or if this is debatable, could you just explain the pros and cons of each?

Answer (score 1):

First, although I would side with option 1 ("more OO"), both options are fine in practice; since normal boards are small. **BUT**, this sounds like the classical application for the observer pattern.

The idea here is that your UI has it's state, which is initially derived from the initial state of the board. The UI registers a change handler on the game's model (board) and each time when the board changes it notifies all observers (the UI in this case) of the exact change. The UI then just needs to update what changed. This has the primary advantage that you don't keep updating things that did not change or need to implement exhaustive comparison logic.